# live who is online on website

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have a small script who show me who is online o website but in db is stored by ip2long and i want to stored the real ip adress of user ....please can sombody can help me with this? here is my codes `

```
<?php

require "connect.php";
require "functions.php";

// We don't want web bots scewing our stats:
if(is_bot()) die();



$stringIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$intIp = long2ip($stringIp);



// Checking wheter the visitor is already marked as being online:
$inDB = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tz_who_is_online WHERE ip=".$intIp);

if(!mysql_num_rows($inDB))
{
    // This user is not in the database, so we must fetch
    // the geoip data and insert it into the online table:

    if($_COOKIE['geoData'])
    {
        // A "geoData" cookie has been previously set by the script, so we will use it

        // Always escape any user input, including cookies:
        list($city,$countryName,$countryAbbrev) = explode('|',mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_COOKIE['geoData'])));
    }
    else
    {
        // Making an API call to Hostip:

        $xml = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/?ip='.$stringIp);

        $city = get_tag('gml:name',$xml);
        $city = $city[1];

        $countryName = get_tag('countryName',$xml);
        $countryName = $countryName[0];

        $countryAbbrev = get_tag('countryAbbrev',$xml);
        $countryAbbrev = $countryAbbrev[0];

        // Setting a cookie with the data, which is set to expire in a month:
        setcookie('geoData',$city.'|'.$countryName.'|'.$countryAbbrev, time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
    }

    $countryName = str_replace('(Unknown Country?)','UNKNOWN',$countryName);

    // In case the Hostip API fails:

    if (!$countryName)
    {
        $countryName='UNKNOWN';
        $countryAbbrev='XX';
        $city='(Unknown City?)';
    }

    mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_who_is_online (ip,city,country,countrycode)
                    VALUES(".$intIp.",'".$city."','".$countryName."','".$countryAbbrev."')");
}
else
{
    // If the visitor is already online, just update the dt value of the row:
    mysql_query("UPDATE tz_who_is_online SET dt=NOW() WHERE ip=".$intIp);
}

// Removing entries not updated in the last 10 minutes:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tz_who_is_online WHERE dt<SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 0:10:0')");

// Counting all the online visitors:
list($totalOnline) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tz_who_is_online"));

// Outputting the number as plain text:
echo $totalOnline;

?>




and this is for functions:


<?php


function get_tag($tag,$xml)
{
    preg_match_all('/<'.$tag.'>(.*)<\/'.$tag.'>$/imU',$xml,$match);
    return $match[1];
}

function is_bot()
{
    /* This function will check whether the visitor is a search engine robot */

    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;   // Not a bot
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I store IP addresses in dotted representation, rather than integer representation (ip2long)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322282/how-can-i-store-ip-addresses-in-dotted-representation-rather-than-integer-repre)

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses *should* be stored as the result of the `ip2long` function. You can then use the `long2ip` function to convert the integer to a dot-notation IP address when you fetch the result from the database.

Preparing an IP address to be inserted from the database:

```
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Taking a database from the database and returning it in the dotted-notation format:

```
$ip = long2ip($row['ip_address']);
```

Simples.

Comment: yes i know but when i replace the function ip2long with long2ip it show me the same....i dont know how to do it....im not a expert in php:( can you help me please with a specific code?

Comment: somebody helpppppp please:)

Comment: The normal flow is, when you save an IP address to the database you first pass it through the `ip2long` function to get an integer. Then, when fetching rows from the database, you pass the IP result through `long2ip` to get the original **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX** –style address.

Comment: pffff i understand but i dont have the knowlege to do theat do you can help me with this code please,if you want ....please sir?

Comment: It’s insanely simple. If you don’t know how to use a function then read the PHP manual.

Comment: @alex from your last comment sounds like you don't want to learn, just to have other people write code for you and do your job. Well, you are in the wrong place for this. My best advice is to hire a programmer. "don't have the knowledge to do that" should mean for a programmer that he/she will **learn** and gain that missing knowledge..

Comment: no you dont understand me ....sorry ,pm im fix theat problem but give me an error 


Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a7078942/public_html/online.php on line 17 can you tell me what i must to do?