# How can I store IP addresses in dotted representation, rather than integer representation (ip2long)?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This function is intended to store who is online for administration. It stores the IP address in a database using `ip2long`. For example, `2130706433`. I'm just learning PHP, and I don't know how to pass strings and suchlike

Here is my code.

```
<?php

require "connect.php";
require "functions.php";

// We don't want web bots scewing our stats:
if(is_bot()) die();



$stringIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$intIp = ip2long($stringIp);


// Checking wheter the visitor is already marked as being online:
$inDB = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tz_who_is_online WHERE ip=".$intIp);

if(!mysql_num_rows($inDB))
{
    // This user is not in the database, so we must fetch
    // the geoip data and insert it into the online table:

    if($_COOKIE['geoData'])
    {
        // A "geoData" cookie has been previously set by the script, so we will use it


        list($city,$countryName,$countryAbbrev) = explode('|',mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_COOKIE['geoData'])));
    }
    else
    {


        $xml = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/?ip='.$stringIp);

        $city = get_tag('gml:name',$xml);
        $city = $city[1];

        $countryName = get_tag('countryName',$xml);
        $countryName = $countryName[0];

        $countryAbbrev = get_tag('countryAbbrev',$xml);
        $countryAbbrev = $countryAbbrev[0];


        setcookie('geoData',$city.'|'.$countryName.'|'.$countryAbbrev, time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
    }

    $countryName = str_replace('(Unknown Country?)','UNKNOWN',$countryName);

    // In case the Hostip API fails:

    if (!$countryName)
    {
        $countryName='UNKNOWN';
        $countryAbbrev='XX';
        $city='(Unknown City?)';
    }

    mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_who_is_online (ip,city,country,countrycode)
                    VALUES(".$intIp.",'".$city."','".$countryName."','".$countryAbbrev."')");
}
else
{
    // If the visitor is already online, just update the dt value of the row:
    mysql_query("UPDATE tz_who_is_online SET dt=NOW() WHERE ip=".$intIp);
}

// Removing entries not updated in the last 10 minutes:
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tz_who_is_online WHERE dt<SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 0:10:0')");

// Counting all the online visitors:
list($totalOnline) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tz_who_is_online"));

// Outputting the number as plain text:
echo $totalOnline;

?>
```

And here is my function code

```
 <?php


function get_tag($tag,$xml)
{
    preg_match_all('/<'.$tag.'>(.*)<\/'.$tag.'>$/imU',$xml,$match);
    return $match[1];
}

function is_bot()
{
    /* This function will check whether the visitor is a search engine robot */

    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;   // Not a bot
}
?>
```

Can somebody help me understand how to use this small script, please?

Comment: what does bot detection code have to do with database operations? reduce that wall of code to a RELEVANT sample.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Do you need the "ip2long" function for an ip address that is in string format? If so I'd revise the question to be just that simple (if that is the question, none of the rest of that code is relevant).

Comment: i want to convert ip2long on long2ip and store the real ip not the outout of ip2long-2130706433!!!!!!!!!!!!!sorry for my grammatic and for title

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14318430/209139

Comment: @alex, ok, I'd revise the question then to reflect that and you'll probably get some upvotes and some immediate helpful responses (and note that you already have the string form ip address in stringIp).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do, could you explain the question again?

From what I gather though, you don't want to store the IP as a number but as a string (either in IPv4 or IPv6 format). It's actually better to store it in this format for several reasons:

- Uses less storage space
- Allows easy lookup for matching against other IP databases, for example to find the country of origin based on the IP
- Allows for much more efficient indexes to be created, an index on an integar is always faster than an index on a string

Comment: ashley im want to store ip and delete them of the users online on website but she store me in the ip2long or something like this ....345345343 and i want to store the real ip adress .now you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stringIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  // real IP address
$intIp = ip2long($stringIp);  //IP address converted to long int
```

Just insert the $stringIp instead of the $intIp into the database, you have to make sure your checks are looking for the right one though. The line below needs to change:

```
$inDB = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tz_who_is_online WHERE ip=".$stringIp);
```

And the insert queries too:

```
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_who_is_online (ip,city,country,countrycode)
                  VALUES(".$stringIp.",'".$city."','".$countryName."','".$countryAbbrev."')");



mysql_query("UPDATE tz_who_is_online SET dt=NOW() WHERE ip=".$stringIp);
```

Keep in mind your database will likely need to change from it's current column type to varchar for this to work. Otherwise you're going to get insert/update errors.

Comment: rick after all the code dont work she store on db the same way

Comment: Read the last comment I made, if the database type is varchar and you've made the changes I outlined there is no way it could be saving wrong unless there is another function doing the saving. Are you positive this is the function being called and there isn't more code elsewhere?